# Load a picture from a site into an Image control

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, web, httpwebrequest

I'm new into Windows phone so I've a question:

I would like to get a picture from a site in my application.

Say that I should use this picture: http://static.lampandlight.eu/img/deltalight-vice-versa-f-led-zwart-goud-mat_89221-1.jpg

How should I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("URL_TO_IMAGE", UriKind.Absolute));
imageControl.Source = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Working-with-the-Image-Control